# Unknown message: Panel when opening gvim

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I literally just type something like this:

> gvim ~/.vimrc

and I can open, edit, and save my file no problem but when I close it I get the message:

> Unknown message: Panel

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `gvim -V20vimlog ~/.vimrc`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

Comment: I did this but it is 8,000 lines and nowhere does it flat out mention "unknown" or "panel"  Is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: But you do get this in the bottom line of GVIM, right? So it cannot be from an external command, or something in the environment invoking Vim (that would be shown on the terminal). Are there any `:echo[msg]` commands?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The "Unknown message: Panel" error shows up in the terminal when I close the gvim window.